# Set criteria in query for fields and fields in nested objects

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

I have a document like this:

```
{
    "InDate": "11.09.2015",
    "Kst2Kst": true,
    "OutDate": "11.09.2015",
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": ObjectId('55f2df2d7e12a9f1f52837e6'),
    "accepted": true,
    "inventar": [
        {
            "accepted": "1",
            "name": "AAAA",
            "isstammkost": true,
            "stammkost": "IWXI"
        },
        {
            "accepted": "1",
            "name": "BBBB",
            "isstammkost": false,
            "stammkost": "null"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to select the data with **"isstammkost": true** in the inventar-array.

My query is:

```
Move.findOne({accepted : true, 'inventar.isstammkost' : true}, 
'OutDate InDate inventar.name', function(err, res)
```

It doesn't work -> It selects all, even with **inventar.isstammkost : false**.
The "normal" query works like I want (without criteria in sub-array). Whats the right way to set criteria in sub-array?

Comment: It is finding/returning multiple documents from your mongodb, even though you're using findOne()? Have you tried the equivalent query in the mongo shell?

Comment: I don't know what you want to say. The query result is fine, but the criteria "inventar.isstammkost" : true is ignored. I want to know the right way to set the criteria within arrays.

Comment: Never mind, I realized that i was making the same mistake you might be making.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will return the "isstammkost": false part, because that is part of the same document as the "isstammkost": true. They are both objects in the array "inventar", a top-level field in a single document. Without some sort of [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/projection/positional/), the **entire** document will always be returned to a mongodb query and thus nodejs will pass them on to you.

I'm not terribly up-to-speed on nodejs, but if this were the mongo shell it would look like this:

```
> db.MyDB.findOne({{accepted : true, "inventar.isstammkost" : true}, {"inventar.isstammkost.$": 1});
```

You will need to find out how to add that extra parameter to the nodejs function.

Comment: it doesn't work `Move.findOne({tablename: tablename, accepted : true, "inventar.isstammkost" : true}, 'OutDate InDate', {"inventar.isstammkost.$": 1}, function(err, res) {...` It gives still the result with `inventar.isstammkost: false`

Comment: I am not able to find a solution to get it working with mongoose. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne gives the theoretical answer, but it is not working so far...

Comment: even with aggregate I am not able to get it working! `var pipeline = [{"$match":{"accepted":true,"inventar.isstammkost":false}},{ $project : { tablename : 1 , accepted : 1 , "inventar" : 1} }]` gives the result with false-value back

Comment: According to the [Mongoose docs][1], .findOne() can take a projection as the second parameter, but in your first comment here you had it as the third param. Have you tried without that 'OutDate InDate' you have as the second param? E.g. `Move.findOne({tablename: tablename, accepted : true, "inventar.isstammkost" : true}, {"inventar.isstammkost.$": 1}, function(err, res) {blargh();});`

[1]: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne